# Displaying ProgressRing in middle of GridView

Tags: xaml, uwp

i have gridview which do incrementally loads data. How to display ProgressRing in middle of Gridview in UWP when loading in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the progress ring to be center horizontally and vertically then add let it get all the space inside the grid. Like this:

```
<ProgressRing Grid.RowSpan="[no of rows]" Grid.ColumnSpan="[no of columns]" 
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Middle" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
</ProgressRing>
```

Comment: That would be great if you mark the answer as correct. Also an upvote will make me happy :)